# Chrome, full white screen, on start

Tags: windows, google-chrome, screen, white-framework

The white screen covers 100% of the Windows application, including the top bar.
The buttons are still there, but covered by a full white screen, on app launch.

Environment:

- Windows 10 (fully updated)
- Chrome Version 96.0.4664.55 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many useless tricks, so I used my precious time to debug this myself.
All you need to do is:

1. launch the browser in compatibility mode for Win Vista
2. navigate in browser to `chrome://flags/`
3. Disable `Enables Display Compositor to use a new gpu thread.`